# Allure reports - Only one report getting generated with parallel execution using selenium grid

Tags: selenium, allure

I am using selenium grid and cucumber for parallel execution on multiple devices. Recently I tried to implement the allure framework for reporting and the report was fabulous. Unfortunately, when I run multiple devices parallely using grid, only one allure html report is getting generated. The allure-results folder in the target folder has multiple xml files generated, however site folder has only one html report.

I am using mvn site to generate the allure report at the end of the execution.

System property for result directory is as below

```xml
<property>
    <name>allure.results.directory</name>
    <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
</property>
```

Can someone guide me on how to get information about both the devices in the html report?